# stopping a python program at certain time and resuming temporarily with button

Tags: python, gpio

I have a python program running a clock and thermometer (raspberry pi + fourletterphat), see program below. I change between showing time or temperature by clicking a single button (gpio16).

**What I need help with:**

1. I want to pause the program during night, 21:00 - 06:00, and clear the display because the light is annoying. With the current code I get the display to clear at time for night to start but it does not start again.
2. If, during above period, the button is clicked I want the program to run for 10 seconds and then stop/clear display. I simply have no idea how to do this, Not even where start.

Is there an elegant way to do this, preferably by just adding something to the existing program. See below.

I have tried various ways of either clearing the display during night time and/or pausing the program until button is hit (but only during the night time, i want the program running during day to show temperature or time).

I have found many versions on finding it time.now is within my range for night but they seem not to be compatible with starting the program as described in point 2 above. (e.g. `if time.now < night_end or time.now >= night_start:`)

in code below function **bright()** sets the brightness AND turns off the display at night start 20:00.
Function **night()** is my feeble start on the restart display at night time but I have not gotten further.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3

#Tempclock working with fourletterphat from pimoroni. One switch to change between temp and clock.
#sets brightness at startup but not continuously.

import glob
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN )
input_state = GPIO.input(16)
  
import fourletterphat as flp

# Find 1s temp sensor
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

# times for setting brightness of display:
# d2 and d3 time dim and brighten display
d2 = 18
d3 =  7
# d4 and d5 time to turn off display for nigh
d4 = 20
d5 = 6

butt = 1

# Set brightness
def bright():
        todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        hn = (todays_date.hour)
        
        if hn < d5 and hn > d4:
                flp.clear()
                flp.show()
        elif hn < d2 and hn > d3:
                        flp.set_brightness(12)
        else:
                        flp.set_brightness(0)

# Define nighttime display off
def night():
        todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        hn = (todays_date.hour)
       
        if hn < d5 or hn => d4:
                flp.set_brightness(5)
                
                
# define temp and time reading
def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c, temp_f

def display_temp():
#   temp = read_temp()[1] # F
        temp = read_temp()[0] # C
        flp.print_float(temp,  decimal_digits=1, justify_right=True)
        flp.show()

def display_time():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        str_time = time.strftime("%H%M")
        flp.print_number_str(str_time)
        flp.show()

# Display time or temp button on gpio pin 16 push button counter "butt" and set
# brightness bright() according to time of day. Function night() turns on display for 10sec if at night, then turns it off.
while True:
    
        bright()
        if GPIO.input(16) == 0:
            butt = butt + 1
            night()
            if butt > 2:
                butt = 1
                
            if butt == 1:
                display_time()
                flp.show()
                

            elif butt == 2:
                display_temp()
                flp.show()
    
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: What is not working with your current code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by assuming that your code to display time and read temperature is working correctly. Also, since I don't have a RaspberryPi with me, I'm focusing on how to organise your logic on the parts that I think you are having difficulty. My code to specifically turn the display on or off may be wrong, but I guess you figured that part out already. Since your question is about an *elegant* way to do this, the solution is obviously opinion-based. What I am proposing here is a simple but sound way to do it.

The first thing to notice is that you want two **modes** of operation. I'll call them `day_mode` and `night_mode`. The behaviour you expect is quite different for each mode:

- `day_mode`: display is always on, when button `16` is pressed, the display should change from temperature to time. It should be active from 6:00 until 21:00
- `night_mode`: display is normally off. When button `16` is pressed, the display should turn on and display something (you didn't specify, but I'll assume it is the temperature). It should be active when `day_mode` is not active.

When thinking about modes, it usually helps to separate three things:

- What you need to do when you **enter** that mode of operation (for example, when you enter `day_mode` you should turn on the display and show the clock, when you enter `night_mode` you should turn off the display)
- What is the behaviour you want **during** the mode. In your case, it is what we discussed above.
- Any clean-up action needed when you **exit** the mode. Here none is needed, so we will skip this part.

So, let's begin! From your original code, I'll keep everything but the functions `night`, `bright` and the final loop. The first thing to do is create a function that tells in which mode we should be:

```py
import datetime as dt
def which_mode():
    current_hour = dt.datetime.now().time().hour
    # In your code you seemed to need special behaviour between 6 and 7 and 18 and 21,
    # but since it was not in your question, I'm not including it here
    if 6 <= current_hour <= 21:
        return 'day_mode'
    else:
        return 'night_mode'
```

To represent the modes, I'll use functions. If your problem were more complex, classes with specific `enter`, `exit` and `during` methods and a full blown state machine implementation would be needed. Since your problem is small, let's use a small solution. Each mode is a function, and the fact that you are entering the mode is informed by a parameter `is_entering`. The function will also receive a signal indicating that the button was pressed (a rising edge, but change according to your implementation). Before that, we will create a function that displays time or temperature based on a parameter:

```py
def display_what(what):
    if what == 0:  # Time
        display_time()
    else:   # Temperature
        display_temp()



display_info = 0   # 0 means time, 1 means temperature
def day_mode(is_entering=False, button_pressed=False):
    global display_info    # Not very elegant, but gets the job done
    if is_entering:
        # Here the display is turned on. I got the values from your `bright` function
        flp.set_brightness(12)
        flp.clear()
    # This is the `during` logic. Note that it will be run right after `entering` the first time
    if button_pressed:
        display_info = (display_info + 1) % 2   # Cycles between 0 and 1
        display_what(display_info)  # Update the display accordingly
```

For the `night_mode` function, we will need to keep a global variable to record when the button was last pressed. By convention, when it is smaller than 0, it means we are not counting the time (so we do not keep "clearing the display" all the time).

```py
time_of_last_press = -1.0
def night_mode(is_entering=False, button_pressed=False):
    if is_entering:
        # Setup the dark display
        flp.clear()
        flp.set_brightness(0)
    if button_pressed:
        # Record when the button was pressed and display something
        time_of_last_press = time.time()
        flp.set_brightness(4)  # I understood from your code that at night the display is less bright
        display_what(1)  # Temperature? You can use a similar logic from day_mode to toogle the displays
    elif ((time.time() - time_of_last_press) > 10.0) and (time_of_last_press >= 0):
        flp.clear()
        flp.set_brightness(0)
        time_of_last_press = -1.0
```

Finally, the main loop becomes relatively simple: check what should be the next mode. If it is different from the current one, set `is_entering` as `True`. Then call the function for the current mode.

```py
# Setup the GPIO to detect rising edges.
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING)

current_mode = None  # In the first run, this forces the `entering` code of the correct mode to run
while True:
    button_pressed = GPIO.event_detected(16)
    next_mode = which_mode()
    changed = next_mode != current_mode
    current_mode = next_mode
    if current_mode == 'day_mode':
        day_mode(changed, button_pressed)
    else:   # There are only two modes, but could be an elif if there were more modes
        night_mode(changed, button_pressed)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

You may have noticed that there is some repetition: for example, in `night_mode`, the code to clear the display is the same code used when entering it, so you could actually call `night_mode(True)` to run that code again. Most importantly, there are two `if`s that are similar: the one in `which_mode` and the one in the main loop. This can be fixed (and the code made more generic) if we change `which_mode` to return the **function** representing the mode, instead of a string. This may be a little more difficult to read if you are not used to functions returning functions, but it is a very flexible way of doing this sort of state machine:

```py
# Must be defined after the functions `day_mode` and `night_mode` are defined
def which_mode():
    current_hour = dt.datetime.now().time().hour
    # In your code you seemed to need special behaviour between 6 and 7 and 18 and 21,
    # but since it was not in your question, I'm not including it here
    if 6 <= current_hour <= 21:
        return day_mode   # Note that this is not a string. It is a function!
    else:
        return night_mode


# Setup the GPIO to detect rising edges.
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING)

current_mode = None  # In the first run, this forces the `entering` code of the correct mode to run
while True:
    button_pressed = GPIO.event_detected(16)
    next_mode = which_mode()
    changed = next_mode != current_mode
    current_mode = next_mode
    current_mode(changed, button_pressed)  # Now current_mode is a reference to one of the two mode functions, so we just need to call it.
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much! Not only did you kick my brain in the right direction but also provided a complete code as an example. There was a few things in it I did not know I could do. Thanks!
I had to add a "global" for the variable display_info in the day_mode definition (see your second block of code) because python did not like a local variable being assigned a value outside the definition. One of those quirks I guess.
As soon as I have ironed out some minor details I'll post the final code on github for others to use in case they are doing this project.

Comment: Oops. I fixed that missing `global`. I'm glad it helped!